# Not able to fetch subcategories from category adaptor in setOnClickListener with json data

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

hello i am trying to fetch subcategories whenever user click on specific category, I am using json to parse data.

my json data.

CATEGORY DATA

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "Maths",
    "q_count": 1,
    "category_image": "qcategory_Category test 1. dPy#NQHA7#PXwRG.png",
    "sub_categorys": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category_name": "General knowledge",
    "q_count": 2,
    "category_image": "qcategory_Category test 2.png",
    "sub_categorys": 2
  }
]
```

SUBCATEGORIES DATA

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "sub_category_name": "Arithmetic",
    "sub_category_image": "subcategory_Applenull",
    "category_id": 1,
    "question": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "sub_category_name": "Geometry",
    "sub_category_image": "subcategory_Banananull",
    "category_id": 1,
    "question": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "sub_category_name": "Gk Questions class 1",
    "sub_category_image": "subcategory_Carrotnull",
    "category_id": 2,
    "question": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "sub_category_name": "Gk Questions class 2",
    "sub_category_image": "subcategory_Radishnull",
    "category_id": 2,
    "question": 0
  }
]
```

Quizadaptor (Main category)

```
public class QuizAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private final int mBackground;
    private List<Quiz_Category> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Quiz_Category> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    private Context ctx;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    String subcategoryid;
    private List<Quiz_Category> categorylist = new ArrayList<Quiz_Category>();
    private String category_id;
    public ImageView image;
    private ImageLoader imgloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView category_name;
        public TextView bellow_name;
        public ImageView category_image;
        public TextView date;
        public CardView lyt_parent;
        
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            category_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtcustomrow);
            bellow_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.q_count);
            category_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            lyt_parent = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.Ripple_layout);
        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public QuizAdapter(Context ctx, List<Quiz_Category> items) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        original_items = items;
        filtered_items = items;
        categorylist = items;
        ctx.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
        mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public QuizAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quiz_list, parent, false);
        v.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        
        final Quiz_Category p = filtered_items.get(position);
        
        //final Quiz_Category p = categorylist.get(position);
        holder.category_name.setText(p.category_name);
        imgloader.displayImage(Constant.getURLimgQuizCategory(p.category_image), holder.category_image);
        
        holder.bellow_name.setText(p.question);
        String url = DataManager.catphotourl+ categorylist.get(position).category_image;
        try {
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //holder.category_image.setImage(url);
        
        holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ActivitySubCategoryDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra(ActivitySubCategoryDetails.EXTRA_OBJCT, p);
                    ctx.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        
        
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return categorylist != null ? categorylist.size() : 0;
        return filtered_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return filtered_items.get(position).getId();
    }
    
    public class getsubcategories extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        boolean response = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Getting Questions...",
                                           "Please wait....");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            response = APIManager.getsubcategories(category_id);

            return "";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progress.cancel();
            if (response) {

                if (DataManager.status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SubcatListActivity.class);
                    ctx.startActivity(i);


                } else {

                    connectionerror();

                }
            } else {

                connectionerror();
            }

        }

        @Override   
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }
    

    public class getquestionsbycat extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        boolean response = false;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            response = APIManager.getquestionbycatagory(category_id);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //progress.cancel();
            if (response) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Timer_questions.class);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void connectionerror() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Connection Lost ! Try Again");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Retry",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    new getquestionsbycat().execute();

                }
            });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
    
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<Quiz_Category> list = original_items;
            final List<Quiz_Category> result_list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String str_title = list.get(i).category_name;
                String str_cat = list.get(i).question;
                if (str_title.toLowerCase().contains(query) || str_cat.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    result_list.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.values = result_list;
            results.count = result_list.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            categorylist = (List<Quiz_Category>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

subcategories adaptor

```
package com.androbaron.dailynews.quiz.adapter;

import java.net.URLDecoder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androbaron.dailynews.ActivityJobDetails;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.R;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.data.Constant;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.model.Quiz_Category;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.CircleBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.*;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.model.*;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.quiz.SubcatListActivity;
import java.io.*;
import com.applidium.shutterbug.FetchableImageView;
import android.os.*;
import android.app.*;
import com.androbaron.dailynews.quiz.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.annotation.*;

public class SubCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private final int mBackground;
    private List<SubCategory> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    private Context ctx;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    String subcategoryid;
    private List<SubCategory> subcategorylist = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
    private String category_id;
    public ImageView image;
    private ImageLoader imgloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView sub_category_name;
        public TextView questions;
        public ImageView sub_category_image;
        //public TextView date;
        public CardView lyt_parent;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            sub_category_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtcustomrow);
            questions = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.q_count);
            sub_category_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            lyt_parent = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.Ripple_layout);
        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public SubCategoryAdapter(Context ctx, List<SubCategory> items) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        original_items = items;
        subcategorylist = items;
        ctx.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
        mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public SubCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subcat_list, parent, false);
        v.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder,final int position) {

        final SubCategory p = subcategorylist.get(position);
        holder.sub_category_name.setText(p.sub_category_name);
        imgloader.displayImage(Constant.getURLimgQuizCategory(p.sub_category_image), holder.sub_category_image);

        holder.questions.setText(p.question);
        String url = DataManager.catphotourl+ subcategorylist.get(position).sub_category_image;
//      try {
//          url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
//          url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
//      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e1.printStackTrace();
//      }
        //holder.category_image.setImage(url);

//      holder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//              @Override
//              public void onClick(View view) {
//                  Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ActivityQuizView.class);
//                  i.putExtra(ActivityQuizView.EXTRA_OBJCT, p);
//                  Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeScaleUpAnimation(
//                      holder.lyt_parent, 0, 0, holder.lyt_parent.getWidth(), holder.lyt_parent.getHeight()).toBundle();
//
//                  ActivityCompat.startActivity(ctx, i, options);
//
//                  ctx.startActivity(i);
//              }
//          });


    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subcategorylist != null ? subcategorylist.size() : 0;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class getsubcategories extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        boolean response = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Getting Questions...",
                                           "Please wait....");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            response = APIManager.getsubcategories(category_id);

            return "";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progress.cancel();
            if (response) {

                if (DataManager.status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SubcatListActivity.class);
                    ctx.startActivity(i);


                } else {

                    connectionerror();

                }
            } else {

                connectionerror();
            }

        }

        @Override   
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }


    public class getquestionsbycat extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        boolean response = false;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            response = APIManager.getquestionbycatagory(category_id);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //progress.cancel();
            if (response) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Timer_questions.class);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void connectionerror() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Connection Lost ! Try Again");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Retry",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    new getquestionsbycat().execute();

                }
            });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<SubCategory> list = original_items;
            final List<SubCategory> result_list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String str_title = list.get(i).sub_category_name;
                String str_cat = list.get(i).question;
                if (str_title.toLowerCase().contains(query) || str_cat.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    result_list.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.values = result_list;
            results.count = result_list.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            subcategorylist = (List<SubCategory>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
public class SubCat_List_Loader extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<SubCategory>> {
String URL = Constant.getURLsubcategory();
private Gson gson = new Gson();

public interface TaskListener {
    public void onFinished(List<SubCategory> result);
}

// This is the reference to the associated listener
private final TaskListener taskListener;

public SubCat_List_Loader(TaskListener listener) {
    this.taskListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected List<SubCategory> doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList<SubCategory> list = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
    SubCategory[] f = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        f = gson.fromJson(reader, SubCategory[].class);

        for (SubCategory flower : f) {
            list.add(flower);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<SubCategory> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // In onPostExecute we check if the listener is valid
    if (this.taskListener != null) {
        this.taskListener.onFinished(result);
    }
}
```

I am trying that if i click on category then subcategories of same category should be displayed in next RecyclerView

if anything required kindly comment.
thankyou.

Comment: You haven't included the code that loads the data for the second RecyclerView. How do you fetch that and update the adapter?

Comment: Kindly check loader added

Comment: any suggestions sir